# Why won't my secondhand iPad let me activate an Apple ID?

Tags: ipad, icloud, apple-id

On the settings under iCloud, if I try and log in on the ID I created this morning, *it says that the maximum number of ID's have been activated on this device*. When I try and create a new account underneath, it says that this *device is not eligible for one*.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure about the wording of the first error message?

Comment: Take it to an Apple Store and have a Genius reset it. Yes, they can. You will just need to provide proof of ownership.

Answer (score 6):

Any device (whether iOS or OS X) has a lifetime limit of THREE (3) new iCloud accounts can be activated using it.

Once the third iCloud accounts has been activated from that device, that device cannot be used any longer to create/activate [new iCloud accounts](https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/icloud/en/terms.html).

Apple allows the primary and the secondary account, after third they do this to you:

[image: icloud]

There is no way around that restriction.

Apple does this to prevent people from having free unlimited storage.

So unless you can use one of the exiting accounts you are out of luck.

Here is some more reading material for the one complaining that I did not provide sufficient link/references:

[Can we have two iCloud accounts on our iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91130/can-we-have-two-icloud-accounts-on-our-ipad)

[iCloud on Mountain Lion: one account per Mac or one per user?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57628/icloud-on-mountain-lion-one-account-per-mac-or-one-per-user)

https://discussions.apple.com/message/20755523

Primary and Secondary account

http://support.apple.com/kb/ts4020

Comment: Could you quote exactly what you are referring to in the link? Sourcing the entire T&Cs doesn't demonstrate the source of the information, especially as searching for "three" or "3" doesn't yield any results.

Comment: Is it this section? "Apple reserves the right to **limit the number of Accounts that may be created from a device** and the number of devices associated with an Account."

Comment: @Daniel I noticed that, but that didn't specify a number as the post was specifying and there were no other references when I posted my comment.

Answer (score 6):

What this basically is telling you is that you have already used 3 Apple ID's on the iPad (must be some pretty shifty owner before you) so you cannot add anymore to it. Its done.

Even wiping it will not solve the problem as Apple must be very tight with their security and with 3 id's being the limit as said before me, for not allowing unlimited storage.

EDIT:

Turns out there is absolutely no fix.
Your iPad wont be able to log into another iCloud.

EDIT EDIT:

Sources:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/24539188

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4005827

Answer (score 0):

There are two good answers to your question. But i did few search and i think this link will help you to create a icloud account : https://discussions.apple.com/message/19867885 . best of luck. hope this method will solve your issue.

content on the link which will help you.

I m unable to create an apple id for iCloud as its showing that the limit for creating a free id is no longer available on your device

iPhone 4, iOS 5.1.1
This solved my question by randers4 on Oct 2, 2012 4:54 PM
Yes.  On the other iPhone go to Settings>iCloud, scroll to the bottom and tap Delete Account.  This will delete the account from the phone but not from iCloud.  Any data being synced with iCloud on this phone will be deleted from it when you delete the account, but will sync back with you sign back in later.

After deleting the account, set up a new one with a different Apple ID.  Then delete this account from the phone and sign back into the original account to sync the iCloud data back to this phone.  You can then go to the other phone (the one that doesn't have any remaining accounts on it) and sign into the new account you just created on your other phone using the ID you used to create it.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different should be more than just a link (because links can break rendering your answer useless). It's ok to include a link of course, but please also include the relevant part of the linked page directly into your answer.

Comment: ok sure patrix. I will do edit right now and will add content of the link.

Answer (score -3):

Another way, besides taking it to the Apple Store as mentioned in the comments, is to wipe the device and restore it.