# This iPhone cannot be used to create another Apple ID

Tags: apple-id

I have been an Android user for the past few years, and recently switched to an iPhone. I was given a used iPhone 6 by someone. But when I try to create an Apple ID, I get an error message stating, *This iPhone cannot be used to create an Apple ID* and prompts me to the website even after I reset the iPhone completely and removed all the previous accounts and settings.

Why does Apple not allow creating multiple IDs from an iPhone?

Comment: See [this page](https://appletoolbox.com/2013/07/icloud-the-maximum-number-of-free-accounts-have-been-activated-qa/) for the reason.

Comment: Welcome to Apple StackExchange! I am not sure why you are having this problem, though it could be possibly fixed by resetting iOS (Settings->General->Reset->Erase all content and settings). That is not necessary though, if you just want to create and sign into an Apple ID. To do that, visit [appleid.apple.com][1] in any browser, and then chose to create an Apple ID. If your version of iOS is ≤9.3.5, I wouldn't suggest setting up 2FA.


  [1]: https://appleid.apple.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't my secondhand iPad let me activate an Apple ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/137396/why-wont-my-secondhand-ipad-let-me-activate-an-apple-id)