# Create new Apple ID solely linked to new @icloud.com email?

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id, developer-program

I am attempting to create a new Apple ID for use with an Organization Apple Developer Account.

I want this new Apple ID to have a new `____@icloud.com` email address.

I do not want to use any existing email address for this account. The Apple ID should be entirely new, with no links to any 3rd party email address.

---

When I go to **Create Apple ID** via the Mac App Store, it prompts me to provide an email address that will "become your Apple ID".

It seems to want an *existing* email address; it's not *creating* a new email address for me.

> Create Apple ID
>
> **Email** - This email address will become your Apple ID.

[image: This email address will become your Apple ID]

If I attempt to type a *new* `@icloud.com` email address into this field, I'm given the error:

> You cannot create a new Apple ID using an existing iCloud email address. If you have an iCloud account you can cancel and Sign In using your iCloud account information.

---

Is there a way to create a new Apple ID with a new `@icloud.com` email address, without signing up with an existing 3rd party email address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not seem possible to create an iCloud-only Apple ID after the fact.

However, you *can* create such an Apple ID **during the initial setup process** of an iOS device or macOS user account.

> Create an Apple ID **when you set up your device**
>
> 4. Tap Use your current email address, or tap **Get a free iCloud email address**.
>
> https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204316

I've confirmed that this works from both iOS and macOS. Wipe an iOS device or create a new macOS user account and you will be allowed to create a new `@icloud.com` address rather than provide a 3rd party email address.

Each Apple device additionally seems to have a strict limit for the total number of iCloud Apple IDs it can create: [Why won't my secondhand iPad let me activate an Apple ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/137396/why-wont-my-secondhand-ipad-let-me-activate-an-apple-id)

Comment: You can also do it in macOS in System Preferences -> iCloud preference pane, and I think in iOS in Settings -> Sign in to your iThing. Note that you can only create 3 iCloud accounts per device (you can *use* as many as you want, but creation is limited). It is not possible to create an iCloud account (or set up iCloud on a non-iCloud Apple ID) via the web.