# Problem creating new Apple ID. Account cannot be created at this time

Tags: icloud, apple-id, accounts

I'm attempting to create a new Apple ID with a new `@icloud.com` email address [from a new Mac user account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374930/create-new-apple-id-solely-linked-to-new-icloud-com-email).

I enter the required information, including a new unique iCloud email address. Attempting to use an already-used iCloud address gives a different error on a previous screen.

I also enter a phone number and receive a 2-factor code from Apple. I then agree to the terms of use.

However it then gives the error:

> #### There was a problem creating your new Apple ID.
>
> Your account cannot be created at this time.

[image: There was a problem creating your new Apple ID. Your account cannot be created at this time.]

What is the problem? Why can't I create an Apple ID?

This is a *new* Mac (provided by work), so I am 99% sure I am not hitting the [per-device Apple ID limit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/137396/why-wont-my-secondhand-ipad-let-me-activate-an-apple-id).

Comment: Your machine needs to handshake with Apple’s servers. This is kind of like asking us why your order of face masks  was not accepted. We can guess, but asking Target,com why might be more productive.

Comment: @bmike sure, but I'm hoping that this generic error has a specific/reproducible cause and adding the error message to Ask Different will eventually get us all an answer. As is often the case with Apple errors.

Comment: Perfect. I will play the straight line and someone else can get clever if they figure a bug or if you find out your address got banned. It could even be someone that used the address before you and Apple has blacklisted it due to past malfeasance.

Answer (score 2):

I like to check Apple system status when I can’t use their online services.

- https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

It has a contact link for when you have an issue that isn’t described. As mentioned in the comments - it’s not easy to know if you need to retry or there’s a more permanent issue, but waiting is always an option to avoid a call to support. I would try once in a few hours, then again tomorrow, then ask support if you haven’t waited a little to try again already.

Comment: everything looks green, same issue

Comment: Was Apple suppprt able to help you as well, @DusanBosnjak'pailhead' ?

Comment: I doubt apple can help anyone. I just skipped the step and came back to it an hour later and it worked.

Comment: They should consider augmenting the message with “please try again later” or “please turn it off and then back on” or something, who has time to chat with tech support.

Comment: Awesome - glad it was temporary. Try again later is a pet peeve error of mine. “this attempt failed” or if you must “at this time” is clear to me.

Comment: @DusanBosnjak'pailhead' were you hitting the same issue around the same time? Mind adding an answer with your experience, if you did get it to work?

Comment: Yes. I’ve added an answer.

Comment: I don’t think it’s an issue of the right moment. I think there’s a batch of macs that have a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I had to get setup on two macs in the same week. Both times the Apple ID thing didn’t work on initial setup so I skipped it. The first app I had to find through the App Store prompted me for the id again and there it just worked with no issues. At no point did I encounter a meaningful error.