# The maximum number of three accounts have been activated on this iPhone

Tags: apple-id

I recently bought an iPhone 11 on eBay. Find my iPhone is this deactivated but when I try to create an Apple ID, it tells me that the maximum number of three accounts have been activated on this iPhone. How can I create a new ID on this iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Presumably to limit account farming,](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/137396/why-wont-my-secondhand-ipad-let-me-activate-an-apple-id) Apple makes it trivial to establish three new accounts on each iOS device or Mac. Since this is detected on Apple’s server side, you can create a new Apple ID from [this page](https://appleid.apple.com/account#!&page=create) (on a desktop computer) or perhaps another device that hasn’t exhausted it’s three.

Once you have set up your new Account, log in on your iPhone with that ID (Settings > iCloud > enter the new ID) rather than creating it on-device.